# hpricot: get image from URL and parse element

Tags: ruby, regex, hpricot

i am trying to get the exact URL of an image inside a page and then download it. i haven't yet gotten to the download point, as i am trying to isolate the URL of the image. here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'rubygems'
require 'hpricot'
require 'open-uri'

raw = Hpricot(open("http://www.amazon.com/Weezer/dp/B000003TAW/"))
ele = raw.search("img[@src*=jpg]").first
img = ele.match("(\")(.*?)(\")").captures
puts img[1]
```

when i run it as it is, i receive:

```
undefined method `match' for #<Hpricot::Elem:0xb731948c> (NoMethodError)
```

if i comment out the last 2 lines and add

```
puts ele
```

i get:

```
<img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51rpVNqXmYL._SL500_AA240_.jpg" style="display:none;" />
```

which is the correct portion of the page i want to parse. however, the error is when i try to get just the "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51rpVNqXmYL._SL500_AA240_.jpg" style="display:none;" part.

i am not totally sure why it can't perform a match, as I understand the search i am running should be getting an array of the image elements and returning the first. so i assumed that i could not run the match on the entire array, so i tried

```
img = ele[1].match("(\")(.*?)(\")").captures
puts img
```

and that returns

```
undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

i am lost. please excuse my ignorance, as i am just beginning to learn ruby. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
img = ele.match("(\")(.*?)(\")").captures
```

To:

```
img = ele[:src]
```

The reason for the errors is that `Hpricot:Elem` isn't a string. Try:

```
ele.responde.to? :match
```

and you get false.

However, you could do:

```
ele.to_s.match("(\")(.*?)(\")").captures[1]
```

the secret is in the `to_s`

Comment: And if you want debug your object, try `puts img.inspect` instead of `puts img`, because `puts img` calling `print img.to_s; print "\n"`

Comment: perfect, this works great. I had tried to go this route, but I tried to_string, which I could have figured out if better researched.

Comment: @Anton thanks. Looks like .inspect is a very valuable testing tool. Never used it before but certainly will in the future.